# Dialer is very slow between dialing the number and getting into the call: spinning wheel for 5-10 seconds

Tags: performance, phone-app, cyanogenmod

I have a Nexus 4 with CM (latest version). For the last few months whenever I dial a number it takes anywhere from 5-10 seconds for the actual call to start.

I checked Android SE and didn't find anything except for this: [Dialer app becoming too slow and less responsive](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15317/dialer-app-becoming-too-slow-and-less-responsive).

However, my case I believe is different. The question above asks about the actual dialer start-up time.

In my case, the dialer is very response: whenever I tap on the Phone icon in the tray, it shows up immediately (the stock Android dialer that comes with CM): I can switch between favourite contacts, recent contacts, search contacts and the dialer with no issues.

However, once I find the contact I need or dial the number and then tap to call, the screen goes black with a spinning wheel in the middle:

[image: Spinning Wheel After Dialing a Number/Contact].
<sup>Spinning Wheel After Dialing a Number/Contact (click image for larger variant)</sup>

This takes about 5-10 seconds like I mentioned.

Once that time passes, it goes to the actual call where I can see the phone number, the contact picture (if available), the drop-call red button, etc.:

[image: The Actual Call Screen after the Spinning Wheel]
<sup>The Actual Call Screen after the Spinning Wheel (click image for larger variant)</sup>

What I've tried:

1. Tried using a different dialer thinking maybe it's the issue with the stock dialer: no difference. Tried exDialer and some other, results are same: the dialer itself is snappy, but after tapping the call it goes to the spinning wheel on the black background.
2. I don't think it's a memory issue as I have 2Gb I think. In any case, with all the text messages I have (I don't delete any), all the contacts I have (including hundreds of Google+ random dudes I follow), the Phone app itself is snappy: everything works very quick.

Any suggestions are welcome as it's getting very frustrating! Thanks

Comment: Could it be an issue with your provider? I'm not sure what's causing the delay here, and how exactly the dialer apps deal with it; but it *might* be the "spinning wheel" is shown while waiting for some response from the network. Could you try your SIM with a different device, to at least make sure whether the issue is bound to the device or not?

Comment: Are you using LTE? If so, the delay might be caused by Circuit-Switched Fallback (CSFB), which has to drop the network to 3G before making the call.

Comment: @Izzy, I'll try a different phone, thanks for the suggestion. I hope it's not network related though!

Comment: @onik, I'm not on LTE. My network is actually WIND Mobile in Canada if that helps as additional info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue.
So, after a lot of work and tests, I've discovered that what was causing the issue was the Prey app. Do you have the Pray app (or similar) installed on your device, perhaps?

After I've removed it, the dialer came back to work normally.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I didn't have Pray, but I had a couple of other apps for tracking calls: Call Log Monitor and Call Control. When I uninstalled them, the issue went away. When I re-installed the apps, they didn't cause the issue anymore. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how you spend hours trying to find a fix and you end up reading the most ridiculous suggestions and you think what an idiot, that can't possibly work...

Well here's one that worked for me: **Settings → Backup & reset → Network settings reset**

Fixed it! Dials within 2 secs now!

Answer (score -4):

I Uninstalled linkedin and problem went away.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Please note that this is a Q&A site and is recommended to give an answer with technical reasoning and link to sources to back your claim.Personal experience might help but a reasoning behind the answer would be appreciated.See [How to answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Tell us how LinkedIn is related to the issue in question and how did you realize that it was the issue, in technical and not opinionated terms?

Comment: Especially: What makes you think that app is causing the issue for the OP, who didn't even mention using it? If it's not installed, it cannot be uninstalled.